# How to find the vector field associated with an ODE?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-analysis, vector-fields

I've got a vague sense that all ODEs  have an associated vector field, but I don't understand the exact relation between the two.I saw an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3068113/do-differential-equations-correspond-to-vector-fields-or-differential-forms-or). It had several advanced math; fiber bundles, manifolds etcetera.

Is there a more rookie level explanation for this?
Given a 2D vector field, say $$\vec{A}=\begin{bmatrix}
P(x,y)\\ 
Q(x,y)
\end{bmatrix}$$
How do you find its ODE? Or given a ODE, how am I supposed to find the corresponding Vector Field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ODE is the vector field. That is, the associated order 1 system is. In that case, the vector field is the same as the (vector valued) right side of the ODE. So in your example, one would associate the order 1 system
$$
\dot x=P(x,y),\\
\dot y=Q(x,y).
$$